Target variable standardization for lasso regression
I am working with different models for a regression task. The range of my target variable is very small:

I noticed a very bad performance of the lasso regression and elastic net model in comparison to the other models:

However after standardization of the target variable the lasso regression and elastic net model improved, while the performance of the other models did not:

Why is lasso regression sensitive to small values of the target variable?
